# Does refreshing your Salesforce sandbox kick off workflows?

Tags: salesforce

When refreshing a full Salesforce sandbox, are workflows kicked off on all of the new records created? Are there other things of this nature that I should be concerned about when refreshing a sandbox? This is my first time doing it and don't want to screw it up. We are not using the IDE and thus I'm pretty sure that I don't have to worry about automatically pushing code to production.

Answer (score 2):

Refreshing a sandbox is a very low level operation and runs outside of any processes, such as workflow, triggers, etc. There's really nothing to worry about, unless you're refreshing an existing sandbox, in which case you lose the data of the old sandbox.